# Access Report - Totalling a variable

Tags: ms-access, report, calculated-field

I have a report that gives me all the time off for a pay period.  I have a lookup form where I choose the pay period start date and end date.  It pulls up all records by employee name that have time off during that pay period, and then calculates the total hours off for that period.  For example, an employee takes a vacation from 9/8/2015 to 10/2/2015 for a total of 152 vacation hours off.  During the pay period of 9/27/15 to 10/10/15, they have off 40 hours.  I calculate this by creating multiple hidden textboxes on my report and then showing the last calculation as the number of hours off.  Works beautifully!  Here are the textboxes I created:

```
'get hours off if begin time and end time off are entered.
vHoursOff = =IIf([BeginTime]="",0,[hoursoff])

'get days off in time period
vDaysOff = IIf([vbd1] = [ved1], 1, Workdays([vbd1], [ved1]))
vDaysOff2 = IIf(IsNull([BeginTimeOff]), [vDaysOff], 0)

'add hours off and days off to get total hours off
vtothoursoff = ([vDaysOff2] * 8) ' + [vHoursOff]
TimeOffThisPeriod = =Format(IIf([Hours]>0,[Hours],"-" & [vtothoursoff]),"Standard")
```

My problem - I want to total the hours off for that pay period by type of time off (sick, vacation, personal, comp).  I've tried:

```
=Sum(IIf([tblCodesWork]![Description]="Vacation Time",[TimeOffThisPeriod],0))
```

and it brings up a box for me to enter the TimeOffThisPeriod.  It's not taking it from the calculation I made on each record.

To explain what I want:  Employee has the following for the pay period 9/27/15 to 10/10/15:

1. Vacation  9/8/2015 to 10/2/2015 - For this pay period 9/27/15 to 10/2/15 - or 40 hours vacation
2. Vacation 10/10/15 - For this time period 10/10/15 or 8 hours vacation

In the Employee footer, I want it to show a total of 48 hours vacation for this pay period.

Please help!  And thanks in advance!

Comment: You will probaly have to add group bands to your report and to group  by type of time off.

Comment: Tried and didn't work.  It's something with totalling calculated fields that are defined on the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are summing `[TimeOffThisPeriod]`, but this field is formatted. Formatting always means that a value is somehow converted to a string. Does this field always contain a value that can be converted back to a number?

Try this:

```
=Sum(IIf([tblCodesWork]![Description]="Vacation Time",
         IIf(IsNumeric([TimeOffThisPeriod]),CDbl([TimeOffThisPeriod]),0), 0))
```

If it still not works, you might have to create a safe `CDbl` function, which does not throw an error, if the string is not numeric, because `Iff` always evaluates both cases. I.e. `CDbl([TimeOffThisPeriod])` will be evaluated, even if `IsNumeric([TimeOffThisPeriod])` is `False`.

```
Public Function SafeCDbl(ByVal x As Variant) As Double
    If IsNumeric(x) Then
        SafeCDbl = CDbl(x)
    Else
        SafeCDbl = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Then change your summing expression to:

```
=Sum(IIf([tblCodesWork]![Description]="Vacation Time", SafeCDbl([TimeOffThisPeriod]), 0))
```